# How to add external API in corona SDk, but no need to require network connectivity?

Tags: iphone

I am new to corona. I want to add dictionary for word meaning but I don't want to add network connectivity so that user can get the meaning without internet connectivity. SO can you please tell me how to add that external API or any other method so that I can add this feature?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can't. With Corona you can only write/use modules in Lua.